# Ketogenic Diet: Fatty Acid Ratios

Tags: omega-3, omega-6, ratio, fatty-acids, ketone

A Ketogenic Diet consists of around 200g of fat every day. We know Omega6 to Omega3 ratio should be between 4:1 and 1:1 and the Omega3's should not be taken in excess.

So that leaves us with at least 190g of fat that should come from Monounsaturated fats (Omega 7 & 9) and Saturated fats.

What are the common proportions in a Ketogenic Diet vs a standard carbohydrate rich diet?

Comment: Are you looking for some guidelines or statistics of observed food intake? And which diet are you referencing (200g of fat for every person imaginable?), is "We know" part of that diet?

Comment: Guidelines. 200g of fat seems like the real deal. "We know"??? Motor Oil?